# Filter an entity by properties of an object that are not null in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have a class object

```
public class SystemUser{     
     public string FileNo { get; set; }
     public string CivilId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string UserName { get; set; }
     public string Email { get; set; }
     public string Mobile { get; set; }
     public string HomePhone { get; set; }
     public string OfficePhone { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
     public string Address { get; set; }
     public int? GenderId { get; set; }
     public int? SystemLanguageId { get; set; }
     public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
     public DateTime? DateOfJoin { get; set; }
     public bool Active { get; set; }
     public bool? IsSuperUser { get; set; }
     public int? SystemRoleId { get; set; }
}
```

I need to filter an entity using this class object's properties that are not null.

For example, If **"Name" & "GenderId"** are not null then I need a result something like below. Please consider **filterObject** as the Object that I received from the POST method for the filter.

```
return await _db.SystemUsers.Where(x=>x.Active == true && x.Name.Contains(filterObjetc.Name) && x.GenderId == filterObject.GenderId).TolistAsync();
```

To check properties that are not null with combinations of other properties will take a lot of coding.

**Example:
Name only,
Name & FileNo,
Name & CivilId,
Name, FileNo & CivilId
Etc.**

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I believe, you should use Expression and c# reflections to dynamically check fields that are not null and filter by them

Comment: You don't need to handle the combinations - since you are doing and, you can just chain `Where` using `if`: `var q = _db.SystemUsers.Where(su => su.Active); if (filterObject.Name != null) q = q.Where(su => su.Name.Contains(filterObject.Name); if (filterObject.GenderId != null) q = q.Where(su => su.GenderId == filterObject.GenderId);` and so on...